# Can't insert item into mongodb object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

So I have this code below which is supposed to create an object with email and password 'db'
to save it in the database. But the console.log(db) on it just shows the _id. It's not inserting any data into de object. looking at the database and you only find empty objects with id too. It was working fine in other project.

```
   var mongoOp = require('./models/mongo');       
   var db = new mongoOp();
   db.email = req.body.data.email;
   db.password= req.body.data.password;
   console.log(db);
   db.save(function(erro) {
     if(erro) response = {"resultado": "falha de acesso ao BD"};
     else response = {"resultado": "aluno inserido"};
     res.json(response);
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are using mongoose, try that:

```
   var mongoOp = require('./models/mongo');       
   var db = new mongoOp({
     email: req.body.data.email,
     password: req.body.data.password,
   });
   db.save(function(erro) {
     if(erro) response = {"resultado": "falha de acesso ao BD"};
     else response = {"resultado": "aluno inserido"};
     res.json(response);
    }
  )
```

Comment: I need to see your file /models/mongo.js

Comment: Already did, the Schema files were wrong. Thanks anyway!